# Добавить ссылку к картинке

Tags: ссылки, javascript

Есть такая структура:

[image]

Как сделать, чтобы по клику на картинку переходило по ссылке с `class="title"`?

Comment: Можно сделать еще одну ссылку, или обернуть это все в один `<a>`.

Comment: Добавь событие по нажатию на картинку, которое будет имитировать нажатие по ссылке.
Почитай вот про это: JS onclick="..."
Думаю дальше сами разберетесь!

Answer (score 2):

Обернуть img в такую же ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('class');
    window.location.assign(url);
});
```